# Memset issue with floating point array in C

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point, memset

I'm trying this simple example to populate a floating point array with 5.6, but upon printing the values out, every value is just 0.0.

```
#include <string.h>
float testArr[20];
memset(testArr, (float)5.6, 3*sizeof(float));
printf("Value 1: %lf\n",testArr[0]);
printf("Value 2: %lf\n",testArr[1]);
printf("Value 3: %lf\n",testArr[2]);
printf("Value 4: %lf\n",testArr[3]);
```

I've also tried not casting 5.6 as a float, setting `testArr[20] = {}` and `testArr[20] = {0}`, but they also result in the same 0.0.

Comment: Read the declaration of `memset()` and then search for floating-point to integer conversion. None of them are magic.

Comment: You need to use a `for` loop, not `memset`

Comment: `memset` converts the second parameter to a char. See [memset - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).

Comment: Does this code compile without a warning?

Answer (score 4):

`memset` fills the memory with 1 `char`, not `float`.